# Does `badblocks` scan for software or hardware failures?

Tags: linux, badblocks

From the manpage:

```
badblocks - search a device for bad blocks
```

but as I try to isolate between software and hardware, I might need a bit more context.

#### Does `badblocks` scan for software (filesystem) or hardware (ssd) failures?

See also Ubuntu manpage entry at: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/badblocks.8.html

Comment: Your question is unclear but, based on what I think you're asking, `badblocks` looks at the device. Whatever data or filesystem is on the device is not examined.

Comment: @doneal24 It seems to be perfectly fine to me!.

Comment: Note that modern disks replace bad blocks (until it runs out of replacement blocks).  Badblocks can trigger this behavior as a side effect, but it doesn't really know about it, and it doesn't need to.

Comment: `badblocks` is usually used directly on the block device, so it would bypass the filesystem. What it cares about is anything that gives errors on that level, so _hopefully_ mostly hardware errors. But if a lower layer hides or corrects those errors, it won't see them. Similarly, if your storage driver (software) is buggy, badblocks might detect that with a write test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer lies in the definition of a badblock. A [working definition](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bad-block-in-operating-system/https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bad-block-in-operating-system/) may be:

> Bad Block is an area of storing media that is no longer reliable for the storage of data because it is completely damaged or corrupted.

It is not the best definition to use with the program `badblocks`, but gives a general idea of what it means.

It is not correct in that it defines the area (sector) as damaged. And, from the point of view of `badblocks` it doesn't matter if the sector is damaged, broken or burnt, it just tries to read the block, and, if there is an ECC (Error Checking and correction), the sector is deemed bad.

The ECC is a method to ensure (most of the time) that what was read is consistent (and valid). It is based on something similar to encryption.

An ECC error might be temporal, trying a couple of times it might happen that the error clears. That is very usual in SSDs because there is a (Dynamic) mapping of physical sectors to logical sectors. As soon as a sector got an ECC error and is successfully read correctly later, the disk chip will replace the physical sector by a different one.

A sector could give an error and, on the next read, be perfectly fine.

A deeper test is to write to each sector with some patterns and ensure that what is read back is the pattern itself. That would **erase** the data on the sector, but if correct, the sector could not only be read from but also written into.

So, to answer your specific question:

- The program `badblocks` will try to find sectors that (repeatedly) fail the ECC and therefore should be deemed as bad. That is a hardware failure.

After a disk has been checked by `badblocks` and found "correct" there might, still, be filesystem, OS, or other errors.

Comment: To clarify, the "ECC error" referenced here is checked by the hard drive controller, and is not a software check.

Comment: Also, badblocks has a mode where it reads a block and holds its data, writes a pattern to it and read/verifies the pattern, and then writes the original data back.   This is mostly non-destructive, but  of course, if this fails, you still lose the data.